# Is it possible to rearrange commands and snippets inside of a Bundle's Menu Actions in TextMate 2's Bundle Editor (yet)?

Tags: textmate

In the Bundle Editor in TextMate 1, you could just drag them around to reorder bundle items or put them inside of a sub menu. I don't see any way to do that in TextMate 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to the guy who wrote the TextMate book, it's not yet possible. https://twitter.com/jeg2/status/185073605451845633

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2014-February/037084.html) from macromates listserv which explains the manual process:

> It’s a manual task currently. If you open an item as a txt file (hold down option while >double clicking it), youll see each item has a UUID
>   like:
>
> 8DEB312B-16CD-4706-AAAE-352E7514D3FD
>
> Open the bundle .plist, and you’ll see these UUIDs entered under menu headings. Move these to move items.

Unfortunately, you have to edit the managed bundle info.plst in order for this to work. Changes to menu items and ordering in your Avian bundle info.plst will not affect menu ordering, AFAICT. Additionally, this means if you disable/enable your bundle, all your overrides will be lost.

Been using TM 2 for about 3 days now and running into all kinds of poor usability issues like this. frown.